# Background color applied to tr doesn't cover full row with insufficient td

Tags: css

My background color applied to a tr doesn't extend the full width of the table when there is one less td in the row. I googeled this and I thought that border-collapse: collapse; should fix this but its not working for me. Thanks

```
    <table>
    <tr class="tr1">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr2">
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>    
    </table>​

    .tr1 {
        background-color: gold;
    }
    .tr2 {
        background-color: blue;
    }
    td {
        border: none;
        width: 50px;
    }
    table { 
        border-collapse: collapse; 
    }​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V3xm8/5/

Comment: Why do you expect valid behavior on invalid code? You have to add a 2nd `<td>` or use `colspan` and everything will work nicely

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a `colspan` to the `<td>`

```
<td colspan="2">
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/demchak_alex/V3xm8/6/)

or add a blank `<td>`

```
<td>3</td><td></td>
```

I prefer to use the first method, but some "table generators" use the latter.

Answer (score 4):

You can add colspan=2 to the td to extend that td over 2 columns.